# Error while trying to upload image to Firestore Storage

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload an image to firestore bucket but am getting error:

> > 'package:firebase_storage/src/reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 133 pos 12: 'file.absolute.existsSync()': is not true.

Here is the function code...

Thank you in advance for your answer!

```
  Future<bool> ajukan(
      {@required Map<String, dynamic> permohonan,
      @required String id, //document local id
      @required String pemohon, //nama pemohon
      @required String mobile, //nomor hanphone pemohon
      @required String ktp, //ktp pemoohon
      @required Uint8List gambar}) async {
    bool success = false;
    bool imageUploaded = false;
    //because we need to use storage bucket,  we need to communicate directly to firebase instead of using heroku

    //FIRST STEP - UPLOAD IMAGE
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    File imageFile = File.fromRawPath(gambar).absolute;

    var fileName = docName + "-" + DateTime.now().toString() + ".png";
    try {
      await storage.ref("dokumentasi/$fileName").putFile(imageFile);
      print("image succesfully uploaded...");
      imageUploaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error uploading image: $e");
    }

    //SECOND STEP - Upload document... do only if image is sucessfully uploaded

    if (imageUploaded) {
      var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("permohonan");
      firestore.doc().set({
        'uid': docName,
        'id': id,
        'pemohon': pemohon,
        'ktp': ktp,
        'mobile': mobile,
        'docUrl': "dokumentasi/$fileName"
      }).then((val) {
        success = true;
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
        success = false;
      });
    }
    return success;
  }
}
```

Comment: image is uploaded or not to cloud storage ? your getting print() on console or not ?

Comment: @LovnishJain No. It's not uploaded to firestore.. I did put print($gambar.isNotEmpty) which returns true, the problem seems to come from the File.FromRawPath(gambar);. because printing imageFile.exists() returns false.. I don't know what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that File.fromRawPath() does not convert a Uint8List of actual image into a file, rather it expects an Actual PATH data encoded into Uint8List. So what I did is first write the Uint8List into a temp file and then use that temp file to upload to firestore storage. Code as follows:

```
  Future<bool> ajukan(
      {@required Map<String, dynamic> permohonan,
      @required String id, //document local id
      @required String pemohon, //nama pemohon
      @required String mobile, //nomor hanphone pemohon
      @required String ktp, //ktp pemoohon
      @required Uint8List gambar}) async {
    bool success = false;
    bool imageUploaded = false;
    //because we need to use storage bucket,  we need to communicate directly to firebase instead of using heroku

    //FIRST STEP - UPLOAD IMAGE
    var storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    var tempDir = (await pathProvider.getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
    var fileName = "${DateTime.now()}.jpg";

    var imageFile = await File('$tempDir/$fileName').writeAsBytes(gambar);
    var uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    var firestoreImagePath = "dokumentasi/$uid" + "_" + "$fileName";
    try {
      await storage.ref(firestoreImagePath).putFile(imageFile);
      print("image succesfully uploaded...");
      imageUploaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error uploading image: $e");
    }

    //SECOND STEP - Upload document... do only if image is sucessfully uploaded

    if (imageUploaded) {
      var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("permohonan");
      firestore.doc().set({
        'status': "new",
        'uid': docName,
        'id': id,
        'pemohon': pemohon,
        'ktp': ktp,
        'mobile': mobile,
        'docUrl': "dokumentasi/$fileName"
      }).then((val) {
        success = true;
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
        success = false;
      });
    }
    return success;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using boolean flag use onComplete() method provided by Firebaseupload task .

```
      Future<bool> ajukan(
      {@required Map<String, dynamic> permohonan,
      @required String id, //document local id
      @required String pemohon, //nama pemohon
      @required String mobile, //nomor hanphone pemohon
      @required String ktp, //ktp pemoohon
      @required Uint8List gambar}) async  {

  final FirebaseStorage _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
 File imageFile = File.fromRawPath(gambar).absolute;
 var fileName = docName + "-" + DateTime.now().toString() + ".png";
  StorageUploadTask storageUploadTask=_firebaseStorage.ref("dokumentasi/$fileName").child(fileName).putFile(imageFile);

 
 storageUploadTask.onComplete.then((onValue) async{
     var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("permohonan");
      firestore.doc().set({
        'uid': docName,
        'id': id,
        'pemohon': pemohon,
        'ktp': ktp,
        'mobile': mobile,
        'docUrl': "dokumentasi/$fileName"
      }).then((val) {
        success = true;
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
        success = false;
      });
    }
    return success;


  }
```